# Best practice to keep track of User's last API use date-time

Tags: postgresql

I have API service that users with given API-key can use with **Postgres** database.

Currently, I'm updating 'users' table's "last_usage_date" column on every usage of API.

But now I see the 'users' table gets pretty busy all the time because there are so many APIs fired. (the table is almost always updating)

I have three questions

1. If a row of the table is updated, will it lock the whole table? Will it slow down(or delay) next look-ups or insert/update? Any performance concerns?
2. If postgres supports row-level locking, will the fact that the user-row is being updated makes other APIs to wait(delay) if it's about to take a look at that row??
3. If this is a bad design to keep track of the last_api_usage_date, what will be the best practice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is tagged with two different database systems. Which one are you using? If mysql, which storage engine are you using? Whether row-level locking is supported will be relevant to this question.

Comment: If you want to sacrifice a bit of accuracy for less contention you could 'UPDATE users SET last_usage_date=NOW() WHERE id=X and last_usage_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(),  INTERVAL 1 HOUR)'

Comment: You'll have to store the timestamp *somewhere*, and a database is as good a place as any. Your question boils down to *"how many writes per second can my database handle"*, which has no easy answer. If done properly, the answer is hopefully *a lot*.

Comment: Thanks for the comment guys! I updated my tags. I use Postgresql at the moment. And I don't quite get what u mean by 'which storage engine I am using'. Is there multiple versions of storage engine per database language?? Also, I'm not so sure if postgres has row-level locking. How do i check that??